# Kotlin button not woking. Same setup works in a different layout

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, onclick

I have a 'signup' page that works correctly and adds the user to a Firebase Realtime Database.

Same Code, with modifications to accept different parameters and sourced from a different layout, does not work. The click event on the layout does not seem to be recognized.

Not sure what exactly to send so I am starting with what I think will be needed so please let me know what additinal information is needed to help.

```
    class NewProperty : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
        private lateinit var dbRef: DatabaseReference
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_property)
    
            auth = Firebase.auth
    
            dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("properties")
    
            val createPropertyButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_newProperty)
            createPropertyButton.setOnClickListener {
                CreateNewProperty()
            }
        }
private fun CreateNewProperty() {

        // TODO add trim
        val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_propertyName).text.toString()
        val address = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_address).text.toString()
        val city = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_city).text.toString()
        val state = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_state).text.toString()
        val zip = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.input_zip).text.toString()
        val bed = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textAddBed).text.toString()
        val bath = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textAddBath).text.toString()
        val living = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textAddLiving).text.toString()
        val dining = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textAddDining).text.toString()
        val closet = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textAddCloset).text.toString()
        val oArea = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.textOwnerAreas).text.toString()
        val fire = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasFireplace).isChecked
        val shed = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasShed).isChecked
        val fPorch = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasFrontPorch).isChecked
        val bPatio = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasBackPatio).isChecked
        val sprinkler = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasSprinklerSystem).isChecked
        val flower = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasFlowerbeds).isChecked
        val fence = findViewById<Chip>(R.id.hasFence).isChecked

        // val rG = findViewById<RadioGroup>(R.id.accountType_signup)
        // val uType = findViewById<RadioButton>(rG!!.checkedRadioButtonId).text.toString()


       if (name.isEmpty() || address.isEmpty() || city.isEmpty() || state.isEmpty() || zip.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                this, "Please fill in all Fields.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            return
        }

        val pId = dbRef.push().key!!
        val p = Property(
            pId,
            name,
            address,
            city,
            state,
            zip,
            bed,
            bath,
            living,
            dining,
            closet,
            oArea,
            fire,
            shed,
            fPorch,
            bPatio,
            sprinkler,
            flower,
            fence
        )
        // save property to database
            dbRef.child(pId).setValue(p)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    
                    Toast.makeText(
                        baseContext, "Property Data Saved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    // If other errors happen, display error as received
                    Toast.makeText(
                        this, "An Error Occurred: ${it.localizedMessage}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
        }
```

layout xml

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textPropertySetup"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="Property Information"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        ...
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_newProperty"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancelAddProperty"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="nevermind"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

rules are not enabled at the momenent as I am still in testing/verifying. (and I am new to FB)

```
   {
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

database structure

The 'properties' container has not been populated yet as I have not been able to push it succesfully.

```
    https://... .firebaseio.com/
users
-N8RGm9rvZ4oYT1o6u8D
-N8RGodvlrjsQEKPz8Fe
-N8RJZxcM4kFUehhgPc5
-N8RLX8tIfQSaydVMWjv
-N8W89_gkgvQ3TrC41Vx
-N8W98Wcxx4djKMooZ9n
-N8WBHJ_caGlOD74gsPI
-N8WaHXNKgCMyCM5J4q8
-N8aPsZPrFxvYp0szQr9
```

Comment: Hi there, can you share your db structure? and also rules

Comment: updated OP with db structure and rules. No rules defined really.... will do that once push/pull are validated.

Comment: can you check if task is successful or not by adding this. `if ( it.isSuccessful ) {}`

Comment: When i put that after onClickListener I still get the same results. 

The App closes when I push the 'submit' button. Nothign shows in the database.

to 'see' if it is completing, where would I see that information during debug? Do I need a breakpoint to verify functions?

I am new to Andorid programming, in case that wasn't already obvious.

Comment: So your app is crashed. Please check the logcat. I am sure there are errors message there

Comment: 2022-08-04 10:34:49.630 6945-6945/com.RTR.rapidresponse E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.RTR.rapidresponse, PID: 6945
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: Can you share your full code at `onCreate` ?

Comment: updated OP above

Comment: Can you confirm which line is error by checking the logcat?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Ticherhaz asked for, and please also respond using @.

Answer (score 1):

First try to move to viewBinding.. avoid `findViewbyId()`
enable view binding by adding the following to your build.gradle

```
    android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
    }
```

and Then initialize your view as follow assuming your layout name is `your_layout.xml`:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: YourLayoutBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = YourLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    binding.btnNewProperty.setOnClickListener {
        CreateNewProperty()
    }

}
```

Comment: I was eventually going to do this anyway so I have implimented it, at least this far but not the population of the data yet.

no change to the functionality though.

Comment: clean your code and make invalidate caches and restart android studio